# Sound not working on Xubuntu but ok with Gnome Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, sound, xubuntu, macbook

On my MacBook pro 2010 I have Ubuntu 18.04 and the sound is working. By the way, I have to start in terminal mode because the related issue of the graphic card for these 2010 MacBooks.

Then on the same MacBook, I installed Xubuntu because I think the ressources are better used with this GUI and the hybernation is working better as well. Unfortunatelly the sound does not work with Xubuntu; I do not know why.

I start Ubuntu Gnome GUI with:

- startx

-> and the sound is working

I start Xubuntu like this:

- cd /etc/init.d
- sudo lightdm start

-> and the sound does not work (I have a virtual audio output)

Do you have some ideas or things I could do to make it work on Xubuntu and why it works on the Gnome UBUNTU GUI ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload alsa mixer using terminal like this :-

```
 sudo alsa force-reload
```

If this doesn't work then try to reinstall alsa mixer

```
 sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

 sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, but it did not work.

Comment: Then try this:-  install 'qasmixer' then go into the menu and choose 'Settings > Sessions and Startup > Application Autostart > Add' and name it whatever you want (i.e Volume Control) then for the command type in: qasmixer --tray then reboot.

Comment: Hi, it did not work either. I have now two volume control: the one of qasmixer and the older one. Still no output hardware device ; just the virtual on Xubuntu. I will resign myself to use Gnome :-|. Now I am just curious to understand why that works on Gnome and doesn't with xubuntu... Regards